# Can't break out of do while loop

Tags: c

gcc (GCC) 4.6.3
c89

Hello,

I have the following do..while loop

```
#define NUMBER_DX_CHANNELS 4

do {
/* some some processing here */
i++;
dx_channels++;
} while((dx_channels > CHANNELS_PER_BOARD) || (i < number_fx_resources));
```

For some reason the dx_channels should reach 4 first before the number_fx_resources is reached. However, it never breaks out of the dx_channels > CHANNEL_PER_BOARD.

I could use an if statement, but that would be added a extra line of code.

Am I doing something wrong here? Is it because I am testing for 2 conditions?

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Comment: Do you perhaps want to break if either of the conditions is false? In your case, if either is true, you keep on looping.

Comment: With which value for `dx_channels` do you start? Counting UP and doing `while ..>..` certainly sounds strange.

Comment: It will loop _while_ `dx_channels` is _larger_ than `CHANNELS_PER_BOARD`. I think you meant it to be the other way around.

Comment: You clearly will have to show us exactly what changes `dx_channels` goes through during the loop, since otherwise...  how are we supposed to find the bug?!

Comment: what are the start values of *i* and *dx_channels* ?!

Comment: Yes, you're doing something wrong: you're making no effort to think about your condition. If dx_channels ever becomes > than CHANNELS_PER_BOARD, the condition will forever be true ... and as long as i < number_fx_resources, dx_channels will continue to climb.

Comment: i starts from 0 and dx_channels starts from 1. It should loop until one or both of the conditions becomes false. Thanks. Normally the dx_channels will become false first.

Comment: If it should loop until one or both conditions becomes false, then why are you looping while one or both conditions is true? Look, just try tracing what your condition says to do for a couple of iterations and it will become obvious.

Comment: "the dx_channels should reach 4 first before the number_fx_resources is reached"... yes, exactly ... so dx_channels reaches 4 and then you loop forever ... that's what you told the machine to do.

Comment: "how are we supposed to find the bug?! " -- by looking at the code and thinking, since the bug is extremely obvious. "what are the start values of i and dx_channels ?! " -- it's hardly relevant. The only thing that would keep this from infinite looping is if `i` started out >= `number_fx_resources` ... does that seem plausible?

Comment: || means or; you need && which means and

Answer (score 3):

You need: `while((dx_channels < CHANNELS_PER_BOARD) && (i < number_fx_resources));`

Note: `&&` instead of `||`